# Is there a way to store a reference to a javascript function inside a user configurable JSON file?

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I am working with WebGL in Javascript and I want to be able to configure different scene graph objects, materials, and animations from a JSON file rather than hard coding them. However, this requires being able to call specific generators in my Mesh class and functions in my scene Node class from entries in the JSON file. I got the materials working because they only require calling a simple constructor for my Material class.

My initial attempt to load these objects:

```
        let scene_custom = SceneLoader.loadJSON('hwy.json');
        let mats = scene_custom['scene_materials'];
        let meshes = scene_custom['scene_meshes'];
    
        let scene_materials = Object.keys(mats);
        let scene_meshes = Object.keys(meshes);
    
        let material_dict = {};
        let mesh_dict = {};
        
        scene_materials.forEach( mat => {
            material_dict[mat] = SceneLoader.loadMaterial(gl, mats[mat]);
        });
    
        scene_meshes.forEach( mesh => {
            mesh_dict[mesh] = SceneLoader.loadMesh(gl, shader_program, meshes[mesh], material_dict);
        })
```

I am trying to save each material and mesh in a dictionary to later reference for rendering and animations. It appears to correctly save the materials into material_dict but being able to generate different meshes from the JSON is proving difficult. I don't know enough about javascript to know if this will even be possible or if I need to drastically change my approach.

Sample of my JSON file: where we have `"mesh": "uv_sphere"` I'd like to be able to use this to call my `Mesh.uv_sphere()` when generating the scene.

```
{
"scene_materials": {
"orb_mat": {
"ambient": 5.0,
"specular": 0.0,
"diffuse": 2.0,
"shininess": 4.0,
"image_src": "tex/orb_tex.png"
}
},
"scene_meshes": {
"orb_mesh":{
"mesh": "uv_sphere",
"material": "orb_mat",
"options": \[24\]
}
},
"scene_animations": { ... }
}
```

An example of my different mesh generation functions:

```
static uv_cylinder( gl, program, subdivs, material ){...}

static uv_sphere( gl, program, subdivs, material ){...}

static box( gl, program, width, height, depth, material ){...}
```

```
class SceneLoader {
static readStringFromFileAtPath(path) {
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", path, false);
request.send(null);
let returnValue = request.responseText;

        return returnValue;
    }
    
    static loadJSON(path){
        return JSON.parse(SceneLoader.readStringFromFileAtPath(path));
    }
    
    static loadMaterial(gl, obj ){
        return new Material(gl, obj['ambient'], obj['specular'], obj['diffuse'], obj['shininess'], obj['image_src']);
    }
    
    static loadMesh(gl, program, obj, materials){
        return Mesh.obj['mesh'](gl, program, obj['options'], materials[obj['material']]);
    }

}
```

In `SceneLoader.loadMesh` I am expecting `Mesh.obj['mesh']` to be able to call any of my mesh functions from whatever is tied to the "mesh" key for each object.

Comment: Bracket notation to access property by name contained in a string -  `return Mesh[obj['mesh']](…)`